# Animation: Image component cannot contain child even when child component position is absolute

Tags: react-native

I am using React Native and is now aware that Image can no longer contain child components.

Problem is I am using Animation component like this:

```
return (
<Animated.Image source={this.props.image}
                                style={[styles.top, borderStyles, {
                                width: this.state.top_width,
                                height: this.state.top_height,
                                transform: this.state.top_pan.getTranslateTransform()
                            }]}>
                    {back}
</Animated.Image>
)
```

An alternative is to use ImageBackground, but when I try to convert the above code to use a custom animation like below:

```
var AnimatedImage = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(ImageBackground)

return (
            <AnimatedImage
                source={this.props.image}
                style={[styles.top, borderStyles, {
                width: this.state.top_width,
                height: this.state.top_height,
                transform: this.state.top_pan.getTranslateTransform()
                }]}
            >
                {back}
            </AnimatedImage>
)
```

**It is now giving Error while updating property 'opacity' of a view managed by: RCTView**

[image]

What is proper way to use ImageBackground in animation to adapt for RN 0.50 breaking change?

Comment: could you solve it?
I have the same problem

Answer (score 4):

You can use this amazing trick:

```
var AnimatedImage = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(ImageBackground)
```

instead of `ImageBackground` or `Animated.Image`